# ffmpeg audio converting and muxing error/warning messages

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a large BluRay collection and want it to get into my iTunes library to play on AppleTV.

I need to convert the different audio streams to a proper format.

But there are several error/warning messages I need to handle.

Here are some example code snippets:

```
mkvmerge -i german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.mkv
mkvextract tracks german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.mkv 0:video.h264 1:audio1.ac3 2:audio2.truehd 3:audio2_core.ac3 4:sub1.srt
ffmpeg -i german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.mkv -f ffmetadata chapters
ffmpeg -i audio1.ac3 -acodec alac audio1.m4a
[ac3 @ 0000000000502b40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[alac @ 000000000050cc40] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
ffmpeg -i audio2.truehd -acodec alac -af "aformat=channel_layouts=7.1(wide)" audio2.m4a
[out_0_0 @ 000000000046bc40] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.

ffmpeg^
 -probesize 2147483648 -i video.h264 -i audio1_alac.m4a -i audio2_alac.m4a -i sub1.srt -i chapters^
 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ger -metadata:s:a:0 handler="Dolby Digital"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 handler="Dolby TrueHD"^
 -metadata:s:s:0 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 handler="Deutsch"^
 -movflags disable_chpl^
 -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy^
 german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.m4v 2>> ffmpeg.log
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] track 2: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] pts has no value
```

_

```
mkvmerge -i german_dts_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv
mkvextract tracks german_dts_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv 0:video.h264 1:audio1.dts 2:audio2.dtshdma 3:sub1.srt
ffmpeg -i german_dts_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv -f ffmetadata chapters
ffmpeg -i audio1.dts -acodec alac audio1.m4a
[dts @ 0000000000332a80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[alac @ 0000000000339d80] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
ffmpeg -i audio2.dtshdma -acodec alac audio2.m4a

ffmpeg^
 -probesize 2147483648 -i video.h264 -i audio1_alac.m4a -i audio2_alac.m4a -i sub1.srt -i chapters^
 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ger -metadata:s:a:0 handler="DTS"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -metadata:s:s:0 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 handler="Deutsch"^
 -movflags disable_chpl^
 -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy^
 german_dts_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.m4v 2>> ffmpeg.log
[ipod @ 0000000002afe740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 0000000002afe740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 0000000002afe740] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[ipod @ 0000000002afe740] pts has no value
```

_

```
mkvmerge -i german_dtshr_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv
mkvextract tracks german_dtshr_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv 0:video.h264 1:audio1.dtshr 2:audio2.dtshdma
ffmpeg -i german_dtshr_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.mkv -f ffmetadata chapters
ffmpeg -i audio1.dtshr -acodec alac audio1.m4a
[alac @ 00000000005a4dc0] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
ffmpeg -i audio2.dtshdma -acodec alac -af "aformat=channel_layouts=7.1(wide)" audio2.m4a

ffmpeg^
 -probesize 2147483648 -i video.h264 -i audio1_alac.m4a -i audio2_alac.m4a -i chapters^
 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ger -metadata:s:a:0 handler="DTS-HD High Resolution"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -movflags disable_chpl^
 -c:v copy -c:a copy^
 german_dtshr_to_alac__english_dtshdma_to_alac.m4v 2>> ffmpeg.log
[ipod @ 00000000004f3780] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 00000000004f3780] track 2: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 00000000004f3780] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[ipod @ 00000000004f3780] pts has no value
```

_

```
[ac3 @ 0000000000502b40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

Only pops up when I'm trying to convert the following lossy formats: ac3, dts and eac3. With lossy dts (as DTS-HD High Resolution) I'm fine.

```
[out_0_0 @ 000000000046bc40] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
```

Only pops up when I'm trying to convert lossless TrueHD, lossless DTS-HD Master Audio is fine.

```
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] track 2: codec frame size is not set
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[ipod @ 000000000338c040] pts has no value
```

Those messages are always present when I try to mux all streams.

Will they disappear when I put timestamps into pts-format in the container?
I can extract them from mkv (mkvextract timecodes_v2 input.mkv 0:video.timecodes.txt 1:audio1.timecodes.txt 2:audio2.timecodes.txt 3:sub1.timecodes.txt 4:sub2.timecodes.txt 5:sub3.timecodes.txt 6:sub4.timecodes.txt) but only in timecodes_v2-format. Can I convert timecodes_v2 in pts and put them into the container to avoid those messages?

Best regards,

Felix

EDIT:
Logs for first snippet: https://pastebin.com/xWq9U2sN

Comment: Do the outputs play normally?

Comment: Yes, they‘re playing fine.

Comment: Nobody has a clue?

Comment: Shoe the complete log from one of the commands.

Comment: Here are the logs for the first snippet: https://pastebin.com/xWq9U2sN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it.

I simply take the video-stream directly from one container to the other:

```
ffmpeg -i german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.mkv -map 0:0 -c copy german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.m4v
```

And than do my thing:

```
ffmpeg^
 -i german_dd_to_alac__english_truehd_to_alac.m4v -i audio1.m4a -i audio2.m4a -i sub1.srt^  -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ger -metadata:s:a:0 handler="Dolby Digital"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 handler="Dolby TrueHD"^
 -metadata:s:s:0 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 handler="Deutsch"^  -movflags disable_chpl^  -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a alac^  final.m4v
```

Works like a charm.
No pts or time stamp errors.
I solved the frame size not set error by specifying the audio codec -c:a alac. Don’t know why but it works.

The „100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.“ error is still present.
It would be great if I could solve that too.

EDIT:
Should be no problem: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7703